# Google Closure suppress warning messages for a particular file

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I am using google closure compiler to compress all the javascript into single file.

While compliance it give lot of warning messages.In my case I have already compressed third party JS files, Which causes complete file to be printed on browser (i saw build progress in browser) for a single error. I cannot modify third party js due to licenses issue.

I am getting tons of warning messages with complete code in browser window, which causes browser to be hanged.

How can I suppressed all the warnings for particular file.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--hide_warnings_for=node_modules/somelibrary` flag.

Comment: I am not using node.js or any node modules, There are bunch of files which i am passing to closure to create single file. How can i specify any specific file name to ignore.

Comment: Finally i have used --warning_level=QUIET to suppressed all the warning.

Comment: Doesn't really need saying, of course, but this works, and also works with the npm google-closure-compiler options object.