# Supress specific warnings/errors

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

### 1. Summary

I couldn’t find, how I can get all warnings for all files except specific warnings (not [**suppression tags**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/@suppress-annotations#suppression-tags)).

In my case, I can’t suppress `WARNING - [JSC_VAR] Using var (prefer const or let)`.

### 2. MCVE

#### 2.1. Data

1. `KiraVar.js`:

   ```js
   var KiraVariable = 4147;
   ```
2. CLI command:

   ```
   google-closure-compiler --js KiraVar.js --language_out ECMASCRIPT_NEXT --warning_level VERBOSE  --jscomp_warning *
   ```

#### 2.2. Behavior

2.2.1. Expected

No warnings.

2.2.2. Current

```js
KiraVar.js:1:0: WARNING - [JSC_VAR] Using `var` (prefer `const` or `let`).
  1| var KiraVariable = 4147;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

0 error(s), 1 warning(s), 100.0% typed
'use strict';var KiraVariable=4147;
```

### 3. Reason for suppression

I use CoffeeScript, that not support `let` and `const`.

1. the official CoffeeScript documentation — [**Unsupported ECMAScript features: `let` and `const`**](https://coffeescript.org/#unsupported-let-const);
2. the official CoffeeScript issue tracker — [**Allow `const` keyword**](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3571).

### 4. Not helped

1. I couldn’t find any tool, that can automatically correctly replace `var` to `const` or `let` in JavaScript files. `eslint --fix` with [**`no-var` option**](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) doesn’t do it.
2. I tried [**`--jscomp_off` option**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options#warning-and-error-management) with values from [**`ParserConfig.java`**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/6a2d09dffb78901591c3cd2614fa1100d461a9cc/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/parsing/ParserConfig.properties#L151-L202) and [**`DiagnosticGroups.java`**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/66cb88323812ff03b5f5e0de09d7962c4ef25009/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/DiagnosticGroups.java#L126-L172) files.
3. I couldn’t find how I can solve my problem in Google, Stack Overflow and [**closure-compiler GitHub repository**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/search?q=%5BJSC_VAR%5D&type=code).

### 5. Don’t offer

1. Please don’t tell me that I shouldn’t be using CoffeeScript.
2. I don’t need [**suppress warnings in specific files**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681479/5951529). I use `var` in many files; it would be nice suppress this warning for all files one time. For the same reason, please don’t [**suggest that I add annotations**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/3487#issuecomment-546453415) every time I use `var`.
3. `--jscomp_off lintChecks` works for me, but it will disable [**40 errors**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/@suppress-annotations#error-to-suppression-map). I need solely suppress `[JSC_VAR]`, not all of these 40 errors of the supression tag.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't allow for the suppression of individual lint warnings.  If you are willing to create a custom build of the compiler, you can:

- added a suppression group
  or
- remove the check

Removing the check is likely easier to merge with future versions.